# monitor lose connect after dist-upgrade

Tags: upgrade, multiple-monitors

some days ago, after I do `apt-get dist-upgrade` and reboot, my monitor suddenly lose connection...I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. 
And here is some information about my monitor

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1366x768       60.1*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And this is what I've done before it died. (after 12pm, I found the problem so I started to remove things)
It's too long so I put it in gist.
https://gist.github.com/linamy85/ccfbcbf0c1b765abb1cc

Appreciate any advice!!! I want my monitor back..

Comment: Open `/var/log/apt/history.log` and [edit] your question to add the entries about actions on the last day before your monitor stopped working. The latest actions are logged at the end of the file. Leave me a comment ('@ByteCommander') afterwards to notify me of the update.

Comment: Thanks, @ByteCommander but it's sad that it's too long ago that history.log don't even log it anymore...

Comment: Do you have files like `/var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz`? Those are compressed archives containing older `history.log` files. Open them with your favourite archive viewer and check the entries in there. If I remember right, those logs should get compressed and reset monthly.

Comment: @ByteCommander the log has been updated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the linux kernel to 3.17+ and dual monitor works!